# Adding Text and Value to ComboBox in WPF Application

Tags: wpf, vb.net

Following code is okey in vb.net and Windows Form Application.

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim comboSource As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
    comboSource.Add("1", "Sunday")
    comboSource.Add("2", "Monday")
    comboSource.Add("3", "Tuesday")
    comboSource.Add("4", "Wednesday")
    comboSource.Add("5", "Thursday")
    comboSource.Add("6", "Friday")
    comboSource.Add("7", "Saturday")
    ComboBox1.DataSource = New BindingSource(comboSource, Nothing)
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value"
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Key"
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim key As String = DirectCast(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, KeyValuePair(Of String, String)).Key
    Dim value As String = DirectCast(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, KeyValuePair(Of String, String)).Value
    MessageBox.Show(key & "   " & value)
End Sub
End Class
```

I want to convert above codes to WPF Application.

xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox1" Height="20" Width="150"/>
    <Button x:Name="Button1" Height="20" Width="80" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="Click Me"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

vb.net

```
Class MainWindow 
Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
    Dim comboSource As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
    comboSource.Add("1", "Sunday")
    comboSource.Add("2", "Monday")
    comboSource.Add("3", "Tuesday")
    comboSource.Add("4", "Wednesday")
    comboSource.Add("5", "Thursday")
    comboSource.Add("6", "Friday")
    comboSource.Add("7", "Saturday")
    ComboBox1.DataSource = New BindingSource(comboSource, Nothing)
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value"
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "Key"
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim key As String = DirectCast(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, KeyValuePair(Of String, String)).Key
    Dim value As String = DirectCast(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, KeyValuePair(Of String, String)).Value
    MessageBox.Show(key & "   " & value)
End Sub
End Class
```

Linked picture shows the errors: https://prnt.sc/kcig7j

So, how can I solve that errors?

Comment: WPF and WinForms are two completely different UI frameworks. You can't convert a WinForms application to WPF without basic knowledge about how WPF works. Read a WPF book before you continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WPF equivalents for the WinForms properties are as follows:

```
DataSource -> ItemsSource
DisplayMember -> DisplayMemberPath
ValueMember -> SelectedValuePath
```

Also, bear in mind that you can set properties in either code-behind or in XAML, so your `ComboBox` definition could look like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox1" Height="20" Width="150" DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValuePath="Key" />
```

I personally would find it easier to set the `ItemsSource` property in code-behind:

```
Dim comboSource As New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
comboSource.Add("1", "Sunday")
comboSource.Add("2", "Monday")
comboSource.Add("3", "Tuesday")
comboSource.Add("4", "Wednesday")
comboSource.Add("5", "Thursday")
comboSource.Add("6", "Friday")
comboSource.Add("7", "Saturday")
ComboBox1.ItemsSource = comboSource
```

---

W.R.T. your event handler, you have a double cast to `KeyValuePair(Of String, String)`; you should probably cast only once and store the casted value in a variable. But in this particular case, you don't have to even cast the `SelectedItem`. Instead, you can cast the `sender` to a `ComboBox` and read the `Text` and `Value` properties:

```
Dim cmb As ComboBox = sender
MessageBox.Show($"Key: {cmb.SelectedValue}, Value: {cmb.Text}')
```

---

Also note that you can just as easily use an `Integer` for your dictionary key as a `String`:

```
Dim days = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"}
Dim comboSource = days
    .Select(Function(x, index) (item:=x, index:=index+1))
    .ToDictionary(Function(x) x.index, Function(x) x.item)
```